# Is the union of a chain of $\kappa$-colorable subgraphs $\kappa$-colorable?

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory, lo.logic, graph-colorings, infinite-combinatorics

**Motivation.** I was trying to prove that whenever $G$ is a simple, undirected graph and $\kappa< \chi(G)$ is a cardinal, then there is an induced subgraph with chromatic number exactly $\kappa$. This is easy to do when $\chi(G)$ is finite. For $\chi(G)$ infinite, my strategy is to consider the collection of induced subgraphs colorable with $\kappa$ colors and pick a maximal element (with respect to $\subseteq$), which must have chromatic number $\kappa$. For finding a maximal element, I tried the usual approach with [Zorn's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma) - without success. Which leads me to the question below.

**Formulation of question.** For any set $X$, let ${X \choose 2} = \big\{\{x,y\}:x\neq y\in X\big\}$. Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple, undirected graph with infinite chromatic number. For $S\subseteq V$ we let $G[S]:= (S, E \cap {S \choose 2}).$

Let $\kappa$ be a cardinal with $0 < \kappa < \chi(G)$. Suppose ${\cal W}$ is a collection of subsets of $V$ such that for all $W, W'\in {\cal W}$ we have $W\subseteq W'$ or $W'\subseteq W$, and for every $W\in{\cal W}$ there is a $\kappa$-coloring of $G[W]$.

Is there a $\kappa$-coloring of $G[\bigcup {\cal W}]$?

Comment: You could use $\ \binom X2\ $ notation.

Comment: Or you could use the established term "induced subgraph" usually denoted $G[W]:=(W,E\cap{W\choose 2})$.

Comment: Maybe of relevance: the de Brujin-Erdos-Theorem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, will do this!

Comment: I think the de Brujin Erdos Theorem takes care of the case that the "big" graph $G$ has finite chromatic number. But you are right, it is connected to this question.

Comment: What if you let $G$ be the complete graph on the ordinal $\omega_1$, let the $W$'s be the countable ordinals, and let $\kappa = \omega_0$?

Comment: Thanks @KeithKearnes for this suggestion... amazing! I was convinced of a positive answer to this question, and you found a counterexample. Would you mind writing this down as an answer? So my approach to the original question (see motivation) does not work. Is the statement I was trying to prove correct...? (What I tried to prove: if $G$ has infinite chromatic number, and $0< \kappa < \chi(G)$ is a cardinal, then there is an induced subgraph with chromatic number exactly $\kappa$.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a counterexample, let $G$ be the complete graph on the ordinal $\omega_1$, let the $W$'s be the countable ordinals, and let $\kappa=\aleph_0$.